# What is a pythonic way to find set of lists which have all common elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

Say I have a list `a=[[1,2],[1.00000001,2.000000001],[2,3],[4,5],[4.0000000002,5.0000006]]`, and from that I want to get only `a=[[1,2],[2,3],[4,5]]` because the other lists have all elements close to some other element of the list. How do we do this in Python? Can `set` be used in some way?

I tried using numpy's `allclose` function but then we have to compare all n(n-1)/2 pairs in the list a, which is clearly inefficient. Is there a more efficient Pythonic way to do this?

Edit: I just used some integers in the example, the inputs are floats in general.

Comment: `round` to desired precision, then use `set`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the values are like that (i.e. what looks like floating point inaccuracy, you can round the values to the precision you're interested in, then use `set()` to reduce things to unique tuples:

```
>>> a=[[1,2],[1.00000001,2.000000001],[2,3],[4,5],[4.0000000002,5.0000006]]
>>> a_r = [tuple(round(v, 2) for v in pair) for pair in a]
[(1, 2), (1.0, 2.0), (2, 3), (4, 5), (4.0, 5.0)]
>>> set(a_r)
{(2, 3), (4, 5), (1, 2)}
```

Comment: Arguably, you could just use `int` rather than `round`

Answer (score 1):

For the data sample in your list and the expected result, as you can use Numpy, i'd suggest to use `dtype` to convert to integer and use [numpy.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html).

So, given your list:

```
a=[[1,2],[1.00000001,2.000000001],[2,3],[4,5],[4.0000000002,5.0000006]]
```

You can do as follows:

```
import numpy as np

a_np = np.unique(np.array(a, dtype=np.uint), axis=0)

print(a_np)
# [[1 2]
#  [2 3]
#  [4 5]]
```

Comment: +1 for the neat trick which I didn't know of. But not handy for the work at hand cz my actual dataset involves floats too